# [NSConcreteNotification isReachable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios5, unrecognized-selector, nsnotification

I'm trying to get ASIReachability to work in my app which works when the connection isn't there but when the connection exists it give the following error:

2013-04-08 12:26:20.501 Your Llanelli Companion[1576:207] -[NSConcreteNotification isReachable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d84d30

I can't seem to remedy this and it's beginning to bug me.

.m file:

```
- (void) CheckIfAInternetConnectionExists
{
    Reachability *reach = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"http://176.31.101.181:8020/listen.pls"]retain ];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:)
                                                 name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                                object:nil];
    [reach startNotifier];    
}

- (void) reachabilityChanged:(Reachability *)reach {
    if ([reach isReachable ]) {
        NSLog(@"connection");
        ServerFound = YES;
        [self PrepareStream];
    } else{
        NSLog(@"no connection");
        ServerFound = NO;
        [self PrepareStream];
    }
}
```

If someone can figure this out for me I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, for some reason it keeps triggering no connection found.  It won't find the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you receive the notification, the parameter to your `reachabilityChanged:` method will be the notification itself. To get the Reachability object, you'll need to get it from the notification by sending `-[NSNotification object]` to the notification.

So something like this should work:

```
- (void) reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)note {

    Reachability *reach = [note object];

    if ([reach isReachable ]) {
        NSLog(@"connection");
        ServerFound = YES;
    } else{
        NSLog(@"no connection");
        ServerFound = NO;
    }

    [self PrepareStream];

  }
```